# Can't figure out how to pass coupon in a URL params on Stripe subscription creation in Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

really appreciate the help on this one, already a 3 hours into debugging this. I'm trying to support coupons during Stripe Subscription creation. To do that, all you have to do is pass the couponId you create in Stripe as an option when you create the subscription for a user, eg:

```
subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(
    source: params[:stripeToken],
    plan: @plan,
    coupon: 'testcoupon' #this works when you hardcode this
)
```

But I want it to reference a url parameter `c_id` so I can make it dynamic, like localhost:3000/charges/new?c_id='testcoupon' eg:

```
subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(
    source: params[:stripeToken],
    plan: @plan,
   coupon: @coupon
)
```

I've declared strong parameters to allow for it

```
private
def coupon_params
    #strong parameters to allow c_id
    params.permit(:c_id)
    @coupon = params[:c_id]
end
```

And have `before_action :coupon_params` declared in the charges controller.

However, the @coupon is empty when I create the charge for some reason. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

///UPDATE, Here's the entire charges_controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :amount_to_be_charged
before_action :set_plan
before_action :coupon_params

def new
    if current_user.subscribed?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Not authorized." 
    end
@coupon = params[:c_id]
puts "def new coupon: #{@coupon}"
end

def thanks
    if !current_user.subscribed?
    redirect_to new_charge_path
    end
end

def create
    params.permit(:stripeToken)

    @coupon = params[:c_id]
    puts "here is the coupon on param check #{@coupon}"

    customer = if current_user.stripe_id?
    Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
 else
   Stripe::Customer.create(email: current_user.email)
 end

subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(
    source: params[:stripeToken],
    plan: @plan,
#coupon: 'test' #this works when hardcoded sdafasdf@dfs.com
coupon: @coupon

)
Rails.logger.debug("Coupon == #{@coupon}")

options = {
  stripe_id: customer.id,
  stripe_subscription_id: subscription.id,
}

puts current_user.update(options) 
current_user.update(options)

redirect_to thanks_path

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end

private

def set_plan
    @plan = ENV['STRIPE_PLAN_ID'] 
end

def coupon_params
    #strong parameters to allow c_id
    params.permit(:c_id)
    @coupon = params[:c_id]
end

end
```

Comment: What does a sample url look like where the `c_id` is present?  It looks to me like you never get the coupon.  is `@coupon = params[:c_id]` where the coupon is suppose to come from because that will not find a coupon in the db.  You would want something like `@coupon = Coupon.find(params[:c_id])` .  But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: here's an example URL: http://localhost:3000/charges/new?c_id=test where `test` is the couponId that exists in Stripe.

Comment: Also, I don't actually have any Coupon scaffolding right now, just holding all of that info on Stripe's end :)

Comment: Can you log out that a coupon is being found in the coupon_params?  Something simple like `Rails.logger.debug("Coupon == #{@coupon}")` and then verify in the log if something is returned or not? Just to make sure a coupon is being found.  This seems the likely failing point.

Comment: Also, what needs to be passed to Stripe as the coupon value, is it a string?  (Sorry been awhile since I worked with stripe)

Comment: @RockwellRice thanks for digging in here :) Yeah the coupon is empty, like the controller doesn't even get it from the URL. E.g. this is what i see in the debugger `Coupon == ` . Yeah Stripe needs the coupon value as a string. If I hardcode it as `testcoupon` for instance on subscription creation everything works. The problem is how I access the c_id from the URL and get it to be set as @coupon

Comment: Before you even call `params.permit`, logout or add a breakpoint to inspect the values of `params`.  Verify you have a `c_id` param.  The `coupon_params` method you created seems like it would work but the name is a little misleading. It's only returning `c_id`. You could just calling `coupon` and not even bother setting an instance variable unless you use it it many places.  Perhaps you can post your entire controller which may reveal something.

Comment: thanks @Derek, i just posted the entire controller. I'm verifying I am able to get the parameter by adding <%= @coupon %> in the view and it's correct there, something within the `create` action is making it so it's not accessible there.

Comment: I don't know what is going on but maybe you can try this.
Remove `@coupon = params[:c_id]` from `coupon_params` method.
It's not needed as you are setting it again in `create`.
Replace with: `params.permit(:c_id, :stripeToken)` and remove the 
`params.permit(:stripeToken)` in `create` as well.
Maybe add more debugging statements before the `customer.subscriptions.create` call to see if you can read `params[:ci_id]`.